# Как настроить дублирование строк?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, visual-studio-code

Юзаю Visual Studio Code 1.32 под Ubuntu. Хочу чтобы как в PHPStorm при нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> строка дублировалась. Никак не выходит это настроить. Гуглил. Вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203752/how-do-i-duplicate-a-line-or-selection-within-visual-studio-code) не работает - сразу говорю. У меня так все и настроено по умолчанию, но <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> лишь заставляет курсор перескочить на другую строку.

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> не работает в Ubuntu по одной простой причине - оно настроено в системных сочетаниях клавиш:

```
Параметры системы -> Клавиатура -> Комбинации клавиш -> Навигация -> Переключить на одно рабочее место вниз
```

Отключите или поменяйте там и в Visual Studio Code будет работать.